# Macro to change the number format to a certain number of decimal places

Tags: regex, excel, vba, decimal-point

I am looking to change the number of decimals displayed in a cell using a macro. I want the macro to work with all kinds of custom formats, I have the following examples that I want to properly change:

```
$ #,##0.00" Test 0.00";[Red]$ -#,##0.00" Test 0.00"
$ #,##0.00" Test 0.00";[Red]$ -#,##0.00" Test 0.00"
$ #,##0.0000" Test 0.00";[Red]$ -#,##0.0000" Test 0.00"
$ #,##0" Test 0.00";[Red]$ -#,##0" Test 0.00"
$ #,##0.0000000" Test 0.00";[Red]$ -#,##0.0000000" Test 0.00"
$ #,##0%" Test 0.00";[Red]8" Test 0.00"
$ #,##0%" Test 0.00";[Red]8" Test 0.00"
"Test 0.0000"$ #,##0.0000000" Test 0.00";[Red]"Test 0.0000"$ -#,##0.0000000" Test 0.00"
"Test 0.0000"$ #,##0%" Test 0.00";[Red]"Test 0.0000"8" Test 0.00"
"Test 0.0000"$ #,##0%" Test 0.00";[Red]"Test 0.0000"8" Test 0.00"
```

Note, I have used `0.00` inside quotes. I don't want the script to change this, I want them to stay that way.

I have started a bit using RegEx but I am not sure if this is the right approach:

```
Sub ChangeDecimalPoints(sRange As Range, DP As Integer)
Dim sCell As Range, sFmt As String
Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, arrMatch As Variant, i As Long

For Each sCell In sRange
    sFmt = sCell.NumberFormat
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .ignorecase = True
        .Pattern = "[^""]+|(0\.[0]+)"
        If .test(sFmt) Then
            Set arrMatch = .Execute(sFmt)
            i = 0
            Do Until i = arrMatch.Count
                Debug.Print sFmt, arrMatch(i)
                i = i + 1
            Loop
        End If
    End With
Next sCell
End Sub
```

Edit:
To show an example of how I want it to change, if I run the following (assuming the list above shows the `.NumberFormat` of `Selection`):
`ChangeDecimalPoints Selection, 2`

I want the output of the above to be the following:

```
$ #,##0.00" Test 0.00";[Red]$ -#,##0.00" Test 0.00"
$ #,##0.00" Test 0.00";[Red]$ -#,##0.00" Test 0.00"
$ #,##0.00" Test 0.00";[Red]$ -#,##0.00" Test 0.00"
$ #,##0.00" Test 0.00";[Red]$ -#,##0.00" Test 0.00"
$ #,##0.00" Test 0.00";[Red]$ -#,##0.00" Test 0.00"
$ #,##0.00%" Test 0.00";[Red]8" Test 0.00"
$ #,##0.00%" Test 0.00";[Red]8" Test 0.00"
"Test 0.0000"$ #,##0.00" Test 0.00";[Red]"Test 0.0000"$ -#,##0.00" Test 0.00"
"Test 0.0000"$ #,##0.00%" Test 0.00";[Red]"Test 0.0000"8" Test 0.00"
"Test 0.0000"$ #,##0.00%" Test 0.00";[Red]"Test 0.0000"8" Test 0.00"
```

Comment: your regex is going to select the stuff between the quotes - but you're saying that's the bit you don't want to change. It would be helpful if you could show what you want to do.

Comment: The syntax for the number formatting : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4 is pretty general, so you'd need to cover many different cases (i.e. one, two, three or four parameters), check for escaped characters, etc. That doesn't apply if you control the input, obviously.

Comment: How about retrieveing the existing number format, and then using Replace(numberFormat, ".0", ".00") if you want to increase the number of decimals, and Replace(numberFormat, ".0", ".") if you want to decrease, before writing back the edited numberFormat?

Comment: I've added the output of what I want to achieve in the above. @AndrewMagerman I am aware that the current RegEx is no good, I kind of stopped half way to ask the question in here, so apologies for that. With regards to the input, I know that there might be cases that I have not covered in my examples above (note, I added three more odd cases), I am happy.

Comment: how do you want to input the desired number format? Are you reading it from the text string?

Comment: I want to change the `.NumberFormat` that is already in the cell.

Comment: This regex is getting pretty close: `[\"].*?[\"]|(0[\.0+]?)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending all afternoon thinking about this, I found an answer that works for all the example formats I've posted above:

```
Sub ChangeDecimalPoints(sRange As Range, DP As Integer)
Dim sCell As Range, sFmt As String, sNewFmt As String
Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, arrMatch As Variant, i As Long, arrReplace As Variant

sNewFmt = "0" & IIf(DP > 0, ".", "")
For i = 1 To DP
    sNewFmt = sNewFmt & "0"
Next i

For Each sCell In sRange
    sFmt = sCell.NumberFormat
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .ignorecase = True
        .Pattern = "[\""].*?[\""]|(0\.?0*)"
        If .test(sFmt) Then
            Set arrMatch = .Execute(sFmt)
            For i = arrMatch.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If Not IsEmpty(arrMatch(i).submatches(0)) Then
                    sFmt = WorksheetFunction.Replace(sFmt, arrMatch(i).FirstIndex + 1, arrMatch(i).Length, sNewFmt)
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End With
    sCell.NumberFormat = sFmt
Next sCell
End Sub
```

I am not sure if there is a way to get this to work without `.submatches`, I assume there might be a way using `regEx.Replace(input, "$match") but I was too lazy for that and this works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for

```
(?<=#,##)([^%"]+)
```

which will match anything betwee #,## and the first quote or % found after that, and puts it in a group.

Then you replace what you get with 0.00.

Comment: I don't think this would work for simple `0.0` type number formats. Have you tested it?

Comment: I tested all your examples

Comment: Yes, but I want this to work on simple examples as well. See my code above. The examples are the worst possible number formats I could come up with. I still want this to work on something as simple as `0.00` and not change anything if the number format is `General`.

Comment: Then the input conditions stated in your question are not exhaustive. The specification of the number formatting is very flexible.

Comment: I mean fair enough but I stated quite clearly that I want this to work with all kinds of number formats and I have listed examples. I cannot possibly post all kinds of number formats.